# How to create database migrations?

Tags: php, mysql, ruby-on-rails, migration

I am new in the database migration world. I use or try to use migrations in Rails and Laravel but in none of them I did not understand this parts:

1.For each modification of database like adding a column, change a field type from integer to string, change database type from InnoDB in Myisam should I generate a migration from comand line?

```
php artisan make:migration ........ for laravel
rake db:migration ..... for rails
```

Or to edit existing migration files and after execute migration? Or create manually file?

2.When Laravel documentation say:

> To rename a column, you may use the renameColumn method on the Schema
>   builder. Before renaming a column, be sure to add the doctrine/dbal
>   dependency to your composer.json file:

```
Schema::table('users', function ($table) {
    $table->renameColumn('from', 'to');
});
```

This mean that I have to insert this code to the last migration file or to create a new migration file?

Answer (score 0):

Most common practice is to generate new migrations for changes. Compare workflows:

When creating new migration:

1. rails g migration ...
2. rake db:migrate

When editing existing:

1. rake db:rollback # you should not forget to execute it first; also, data may be lost
2. edit migration
3. rake db:migrate
4. Restore data if it was lost on first step

Also, when you work in team, each member should process these steps, too. Just too much noise, better to generate new migration.